# Gitolite push is not actually writing to server

Tags: gitolite

I've got gitolite setup so I can clone it and I've tried adding a new key for a new user and adding a repo for that user.

I've made those changes, committed and pushed.

There was no error, but the server does not have the updated gitolite.conf or user.pub files. Also, the authorized_keys has not been updated.

I am using SELinux on CentOS 6 if that matters. All of the files in .gitolite and repositories are owned by the gitolite user and that is the user I am connecting with. I couldn't find anything obvious in /var/logs/audit.log, or /var/logs/secure, but I wasn't sure what to look for.

My gitolite log has something like this when I try to push:

```
2013-09-29.11:18:49 25508   ssh ARGV=gitolite   SOC=git-receive-pack 'gitolite-admin'   FROM=192.168.1.201
2013-09-29.11:18:49 25508       access(gitolite-admin, gitolite, W, 'any'),-> refs/.*
2013-09-29.11:18:49 25508       trigger,Writable,access_1,ACCESS_1,gitolite-admin,gitolite,W,any,refs/.*
2013-09-29.11:18:49 25508   pre_git gitolite-admin  gitolite    W   any refs/.*
2013-09-29.11:18:49 25508       system,git,shell,-c,git-receive-pack '/var/lib/gitolite/repositories/gitolite-admin.git'
2013-09-29.11:18:49 25508   END
```

Comment: I've tried setting SELinux to permissive mode and the result is the same, so I'm ruling that out. Permissions look fine. I do have .gitolite and repositories symlinked to another drive, as described in the docs. I don't think that's the problem because I can clone just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was .gitolite and repositories folders were symlink'd to my backup drive which is mounted with `noexec`. I removed the `noexec` and remounted and it seems to be working.